# How put in unique format date with different format dates in one column?

Tags: excel, date, datestamp

I have data in a column with different formats, DD-MM-YYYY, MM-DD-YYYY, DD/MM/YYYY, MM/DD/YYYY, April-20. And I want to convert the dates in a unique format. Exist some function in Excel or a macro with VBA?

I'd tried with the function search and replace but there are more data in the datasheet.

Comment: Yes, there are functions you can write or formulas you can use that may be able to convert it. Usually the most robust method is to go back a step and ensure the dates are all in the same format. Especially since there is no way of determining whether `09/02/2023` refers to `9-Feb-2023` or `2-Sep-2023`. Most likely your data source was a text or csv file that was **OPEN**'d instead of being properly **IMPORT**ed. This has been discussed ad nauseum on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Text" function to convert back to a single format
=TEXT(Your Cell,"DD/MM/YYYY") => Day / Month / Year
=TEXT(Your Cell,"MM/DD/YYYY") => Month / Day / Year

Comment: If data stored as text then `TEXT()` function will fail.

Comment: If it is stored in "text" format but still has the structure of date, month, year, it will still work. Like this paragraph "9/5/2008" is formatted as text, you can still use the Text function to convert to date, month, year.